# D3 JS Import different csv files based on condition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to import multiple CSVs when a condition changes. 
Let's say I have button a and b, when the button a activated, I would like to read the a.csv. However, b.csv will be imported if button b is activated. 
I use the code `d3.text("filename.csv")`.

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: What condition changes? Please improve your question by editing.

Comment: Sorry for the indistinct question. It would be more clear now.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any HTML code for the buttons? In what context do you use `d3.text("filename.csv")`? In JavaScript you just can use variables: `d3.text(filename + "csv")` where the filenames is set based on some button property.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick answer! Frank.  Actually , I am quiet junior at html coding and I have not idea how to solve the problem. The condition mentioned above is just an example to illustrate that I want to read different csv files. And I haven't do anything yet ( including the button a,b ). So, you mean I can make the filename dynamic and then the d3.text function can read different file ? Could u please give me more hints on how to make the filename dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using D3, this could be a way to import CSVs. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV for more info.

I advice you to do a JavaScript course to understand the basics a little bit more.

#### HTML

```
 <button id="a">Import a.csv</button>
 <button id="b">Import b.csv</button>
```

#### Javascript

```
function importCSV(filename) {
  d3.csv(filename)
    .get(function(error, rows) {
    // Do something with the rows
    console.log(rows, error);
  });
}

d3.selectAll('button').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e, this);
  importCSV(d3.select(this).attr('id') + '.csv');
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/8gvyd4py/) (open console).

Comment: Thanks again Frank ! It does give me a direction ! And thanks your advice, I am learning that by some internet open source but the progress is quiet slow. Btw, I will let you know once I success !

Comment: Ok, good luck! If this answer answered your question, please mark it as accepted (green flag will appear).